# jstree - stop single expanded node from collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

Using [jstree](https://www.jstree.com) is it possible to block the collapse of a single specific node?

I have a tree structure which can be expanded/collapsed at will... but I have certain nodes that should always be open and not allow the user to collapse them.

Is there a way to block the collapse (maybe through the `data-jstree` attribute on the `<li>`)... and if possible, a way to also remove the triangle against the item?

I've tried hooking into the `close_node.jstree` event but neither using a `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` is stopping it happening.

In the following example, I want the "Item 2 - Must Keep Open" to ALWAYS be open, and not allow the user to hide the "Always Visible" item...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#treeRoot").jstree({
    core: {
      themes: {
        variant: "small"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="treeRoot">
  <ul>
    <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>Root
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>Item 2 - Must keep open
          <ul>
            <li>Always Visible</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any option for preventing the closing of the node besides the option of overriding the `close_node` function of the jstree code.

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {

  $.jstree.core.prototype.old_close_node = $.jstree.core.prototype.close_node;
  $.jstree.core.prototype.close_node = function(obj, animation) {
    node_obj = this.get_node(obj);
    // in case the flag exists - don't continue to with the original function.
    if (node_obj.state.prevent_close) {
      return;
    }
    this.old_close_node(obj, animation);
  }
  
  $("#treeRoot").on('loaded.jstree', function() {
    $('#treeRoot li').each((index, el) => {
      if ($(el).data('jstree') && $(el).data('jstree').prevent_close) {
        $(el).addClass('prevent-close');
      }
    })
  }).jstree({
    core: {
      themes: {
        variant: "small"
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.jstree-default-small .jstree-open.prevent-close>.jstree-ocl {
  background-position: -71px -7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="treeRoot">
  <ul>
    <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>Root
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <!--                             v-- this is the flag to prevent the close -->
        <li data-jstree='{"opened":true, "prevent_close": true}'>Item 2 - Must keep open
          <ul>
            <li>Always Visible</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I didn't have the time to handle with the triangle, let me know if you have issues there, I'll try to find a solution for this one as well.

Comment: Thanks for your time Dekel... is your code supposed to stop the collapse, or demonstrate how to override the close functionality?

Comment: both, actually :) try to click on the "root" element (to close it).

Comment: Ah, that's something I hadn't tried... as it's the "Item 2 - Must keep open" that I'm trying to block the closure of.  Every parent-node should act as normal

Comment: Just add the `"prevent_close": true` where you need it... I changed the code to set the prevent_close on the second element. check it now.

Comment: Interesting... many thanks for the idea.  Never keen on overriding functionality, in case the underlying functionality changes in future updates.  Will have a play and let you know how I get on.  If you do figure out removing the triangle, please let me know

Comment: Fixed also the triangle.

Comment: Indeed you have... excellent :-)  Am currently playing, will get back to you shortly

Comment: Set the class from inside the loaded method (so you don't need to set both the data and the class.

Comment: Great stuff... thanks for all your help.  I've got it working, but instead of using the `data-jstree`, I've included an extra `data-blockcollapse="1"` attribute.  Then I trigger off `data.blockcollapse` and use `li[data-blockcollapse]` in the css

Comment: Check my update on the css to make sure the code is more readable.

Comment: I realise it's highly subjective, but I feel my way of doing it is more readable... I set the `data-blockcollapse="1"` on all appropriate nodes in the code-behind when generating the structure, and there is no need to do CSS processing in jQuery, the css takes care of it all. Thanks again for your efforts

Comment: Sure :) no problem.